# Uncaught TypeError while using value from a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, camanjs

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(".filter").on('click', function (e) {
     var filterFunction = $(this).data('strength');
     console.log(filterFunction); // Outputs brightness(10)
     Caman('#canvas', function () {  
           this.filterFunction.render();
     });
});
```

This is the exact error I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined`

I want to use a single piece of code to handle all the filters. Before trying the above code, the actual code was:

```
$brightness.on('click', function (e) {
     Caman('#canvas', function () {
         this.brightness(10).render();
     });
});
```

but this way, I will have to create a different handler for each filter. I want to avoid that. Can anyone please help me resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like you will need to understand how the `this` keyword works in Javascript. [Here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) is an article you can start with.

Answer (score 0):

this is contextual when bound to different handler so instead of running the code of event again just fire that event manually when you need to execute that code

```
$(".filter").on('click', function (e) {
     $brightness.trigger('click'); //trigger manually click event of $brightness also keep the $brightness handler as it is written
});
```